# How to clone a jQuery Listen plugin event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, clone, listen

I have some `<tr>` elements on my page with a `click()` event attached to an image that sits inside each one. I use this code

```
$(this).clone(true).appendTo("table#foo");
```

to do the following:

- copy those `<tr>`s into a different table
- preserve the click events on the images inside the `<tr>`s (because of the `true` argument)

All of that works fine. Now I have added a [jQuery Listen](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Listen) event to those `<tr>`s, so that a user doesn't have to aim precisely: he/she can click anywhere on the `<tr>` and I can pass the click to the image.

It's coded like this:

```
$('tr.record').listen('click','td',function(){
  $(this).parent().find("img.clickable").click();
});
```

The listen() event works fine on the original item, but **on the cloned item, the listen() event fails.** The image's click event still works fine.

Here is what Firebug tells me:

```
m(this, e.type) is undefined
```

...and it references line 9 of jquery.listen-1.0.3-min.js.

**How can I can make the listen() event work on the cloned elements?**

### Update

By default, jQuery doesn't copy events on cloned elements, but [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copyEvents) is made to do that.

Meanwhile, the author of the listen() plugin suggested a different strategy - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ariel Flesler, creator of the listen() plugin, gave me this advice via email:

*"I think this can be solved in another way. The idea of Listen (and
event delegation) is to actually avoid all the copying of events for
new elements."*

*"You could simply do:"*

```
$('table#foo').listen('click','td',function(){
 $(this).parent().find("img.clickable").click();
});
```

*"Or even:"*

```
$.listen('click','td',function(){
 $(this).parent().find("img.clickable").click();
});
```

*"The first example will use the table as listener. In the 2nd one, the
`<html>` tag is used. So no matter if you add new td/tr/tables. It'll
still work."*